# What poison in Poirot: The Big Four?

Tags: poirot

What drug was used in the itv version of [The Big Four](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2119592/)? The one that caused the paralysis in the two hostages and one of the murder victims.

Comment: is it a novel question? I can't see any film or television series for the same name. If the answer is yes, then it belongs to [Science Fiction and Fantasy](http://scifi.stackexchange.com).

Comment: I am referring to the itv series: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Agatha_Christie%27s_Poirot_episodes#Series_13_.282013.29

Comment: I cannot seem to find any reference to a specific chemical, but it might be worth checking out the two below. Both have been used in other Poirot stories: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coniine          
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conium

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By now, I have watched the relevant parts again, and although I think Vedran's answer is correct for the book version of the story, in the TV series, something different was used. I listened to it closely again, and understood something like Jasmine. There is a variety of Jasmine, the [Yellow Jasmine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelsemium_sempervirens), which seems to be very poisonous, containing [Gelsemine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelsemine). This poison is similar to Strychnine, it seems. The Wikipedia page on ["The Big Four"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Big_Four_%28novel%29#Agatha_Christie.27s_Poirot) seems to agree:

> [...] orchestrates the entire Big Four setup, feeding the press
>   with sensational clues and threatening letters and killing his victims
>   to implicate the Peace Party members (whom he then kidnaps and drugs
>   with immobilising gelsemine) [...]

I personally am wondering how Gelsemine can cause such paralysis, since it rather seems to produce convulsions. But that's fiction for you.

Answer (score 2):

It was Belladonna:

> **Belladonna** (also known as [Deadly Nightshade](http://aliciac.hubpages.com/hub/Belladonna-the-Deadly-Nightshade), Devil’s Berries or Death Cherries) features in *The Caribbean Mystery* and *The Big Four*. Foliage and berries are toxic, containing a mixture of alkaloids including hyoscine (scopolamine) and atropine (both anti-cholinergic anti-muscurinic in action) and hyoscyamine (an isomer of atropine). Both the [Emperor Augustus](http://darkside.hubpages.com/hub/augustus) and Agrippina (wife and sister of Claudius) used belladonna to poison contemporaries. Symptoms include dilated pupils, blurred vision, tachycardia, dry mouth, slurred speech, urinary retention, confusion and hallucinations.
>
> Source: [Poisons Used In Agatha Christie](http://anneharrison.hubpages.com/hub/The-Poisons-of-Agatha-Christe)

Although paralysis is not mentioned here, if you follow the first of the two links, you get:

> Severe poisoning can cause paralysis, a coma and respiratory failure.